# Remove XML Parent Elements based on list of values using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Lets say I have a list of GlobalID's:

```
4EAED006DCDC
2AE33C272408
C3DE024CAC11
```

And some XML with configs from my app's DB:

```xml
  <ConfigKeyValuesTable>
    <ConfigKeyValues>
      <KeyValue>true</KeyValue>
      <CreatedDate>2020-09-04T09:42:57.6685544-05:00</CreatedDate>
      <GlobalId>2AE33C272408</GlobalId>
      <IsActive>1</IsActive>
      <ModifiedDate>2021-09-28T00:38:40.5075315-05:00</ModifiedDate>
    </ConfigKeyValues>
    <ConfigKeyValues>
      <KeyValue>false</KeyValue>
      <CreatedDate>2020-09-04T09:42:57.6685544-05:00</CreatedDate>
      <GlobalId>8E761269F5AA</GlobalId>
      <IsActive>1</IsActive>
      <ModifiedDate>2021-09-28T00:38:40.5845906-05:00</ModifiedDate>
    </ConfigKeyValues>
  </ConfigKeyValuesTable>
```

How would I go about using that list to remove the parent  for all instances where the GlobalId matches an entry from my list? I've seen some examples that allow you to remove the parent attribute from 1 match like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ConfigKeyValues[GlobalId='2AE33C272408']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How do you get that list? Is it hard coded in your transformation? Passed as a parameter? In which format?

Comment: Also please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: I have a list of GlobalId's in a .txt file separated by newline.

Comment: I would be using XML Tools Plugin for Np++ which allows for XSL Transformation. https://github.com/morbac/xmltools

Comment: For me using XML Tools Plugin in NotePad++ was more of a headache than anything. Would be simpler for your to download the latest version of SaxonHE, use the XSLT3 file reading capabilities and be done.

Comment: This does not answer neither question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Hence why I put this as a comment, a suggestion for a simpler solution.

Comment: @Sebastien The comment was addressed to the OP.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry about that!